# grouping the table data(id,machine_id,telemetry_time,riskscore,current) by plant shift time and considering date as shift startime

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, average, date-arithmetic

I have a table with timestamp and someother  metrics like riskscore and current of a machine.Here plant shift starts @ 08:00 am  and ends @ next day 08:00am.
i want to group the data by day(shift: 08:00am to nextday 08:00am) of timetamp and label it as shift start date.i have a 6months of data.)
expected output:

```
machine | date       | avg_riskscore | avg_current
2       | 2020-12-02 |          25.5   |        10
```

here this record is  group of data between '2020-12-02 08:00:00' and '2020-12-03 08:00:00'  and should insert with date '2020-12-02'

here i need to aggregate the 6 months of data like this.

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0a3f02eb732e77bff38e11376d8e5566)**

Comment: Could you create an example at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13 ? And show us what you already tried?

Comment: i havent tried anything...i will give you example.

Comment: Could you put a link to your DB Fiddle so we can play with your example? You can't expect others to create your example.

Comment: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0a3f02eb732e77bff38e11376d8e5566)   created sample data in db fiddle. @FrankHeikens please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just offset the timestamp by 8 hours, then truncate to date and aggregate. Based on your fiddle, that would be:

```
select 
    equipment_id, 
    (telemetry_time - interval '8 hour')::date as date, 
    avg(riskscore) as avg_riskscore,
    avg(i_rms) as avg_i_rms
from telemetry_test 
group by equipment_id, date
```